# YouTube Internal API (InnerTube) has not been used in project

Tags: youtube, youtube-api, youtube-data-api, youtube-iframe-api

I was playing youtube video on my application using youtubei api. One day videos got very slow. I figured api key [`AIzaSyAO_FJ2SlqU8Q4STEHLGCilw_Y9_11qcW8`] was overused. I tried to replace it with my own api key but it only responded with `403 Forbidden YouTube Internal API (InnerTube) has not been used in project`. How do I setup my own key?
What I tried:

1. Enabled Youtube Data api V3, created credential
2. Tried go to https://console.developers.google.com/apis/api/youtubei.googleapis.com/overview it failed to load

URL: [https://www.youtube.com/youtubei/v1/player?key=[MY](https://www.youtube.com/youtubei/v1/player?key=%5BMY) API key]

RESPONSE:

```json
{
    "error": {
        "code": 403,
        "message": "YouTube Internal API (InnerTube) has not been used in project 910740975396 before or it is disabled. Enable it by visiting https://console.developers.google.com/apis/api/youtubei.googleapis.com/overview?project=910740975396 then retry. If you enabled this API recently, wait a few minutes for the action to propagate to our systems and retry.",
        "errors": [
            {
                "message": "YouTube Internal API (InnerTube) has not been used in project 910740975396 before or it is disabled. Enable it by visiting https://console.developers.google.com/apis/api/youtubei.googleapis.com/overview?project=910740975396 then retry. If you enabled this API recently, wait a few minutes for the action to propagate to our systems and retry.",
                "domain": "usageLimits",
                "reason": "accessNotConfigured",
                "extendedHelp": "https://console.developers.google.com"
            }
        ],
        "status": "PERMISSION_DENIED",
        "details": [
            {
                "@type": "type.googleapis.com/google.rpc.Help",
                "links": [
                    {
                        "description": "Google developers console API activation",
                        "url": "https://console.developers.google.com/apis/api/youtubei.googleapis.com/overview?project=[project id]"
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                "@type": "type.googleapis.com/google.rpc.ErrorInfo",
                "reason": "SERVICE_DISABLED",
                "domain": "googleapis.com",
                "metadata": {
                    "service": "youtubei.googleapis.com",
                    "consumer": "projects/[project id]"
                }
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Comment: [Everybody has the same YouTube UI key](https://github.com/Benjamin-Loison/YouTube-operational-API/blob/b91dc265a08240ff1392c95b726c218637f24b6e/constants.php#L19) (`AIzaSyAO_FJ2SlqU8Q4STEHLGCilw_Y9_11qcW8`) so as far as I know you can't modify it in any successful way. The YouTube UI key isn't related to YouTube Data API v3 ones.

Comment: @BenjaminLoison thank you. saved me trouble for wasting time on configuring key.